# Do we have a questions per day and month limit here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Do we have a question posts per day and month limit on Biology.SE?

I thought system wide limits were adopted: max. 6 posts/day, max. 50 posts/month.

It was kind of hush-hush, but I thought it was in place across all SE sites. So I was surprised to find 8 questions by the same user on the "front page".

"Good" questions are usually hard to ask. A person doesn't commonly have a half-dozen "good" questions per day. Of course, "good" has to be determined by each site.

The limit is in place to prevent exactly this. I know it's in effect on at least two other SE sites.

Comment: If you're talking about who I think you're talking about, then in this case, these were the user's first questions, so they may not have been aware of proper site etiquette.

Comment: @HDE226868 - Agreed. New people deserve some grace. The purpose of the limits, though, is to take the person out of the equation, that is, to make it *not-personal*, not biased, not related to their perception (or its lack) of cues. The limits are there for everyone, since usually one good question is hard enough to formulate well, let alone 8.

Comment: I totally understand. I wasn't too thrilled with the quality of the questions.

Comment: Note that the [front page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) and the [questions page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions) are different as far as what questions appear on them. Questions on the question page appear in the order that they are asked, and questions on the front page appear as they are interacted with (asked, answered, edited).

Comment: For example, if I edited several of my past questions in a short span of time, they would all appear on the [front](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) page, but not the [questions](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions) page. (I'm not sure which of the two you're talking about)

Comment: @Luigi - Good point. These appeared on the newest questions page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are limits see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). Below, I have added the information you are looking for from the meta. I also remember that SX goes by UTC time so the day changes at about 7pm for people in the US Eastern time zone. Additionally, there is no way around it according to [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) since it goes by IP and account. So even if the said user used a different IP, they wouldn't have been able to post since it was all under the same account [[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours).

---

> Asking

- Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes (90 minutes on Stack Overflow)

  - Users limited by Anti-Recidivism System, one question per week
  - Users limited from asking questions for 1 - 7 days based on the
    performance of their previous questions
- Users < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
- Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds
- On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Math (not active on
  all other sites)

  - maximum of 6 questions per day
  - maximum of 50 questions per 30 days

  Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period

> Answering

- Users < 100 rep can't answer their own question for 8 hours
- Users < 125 rep, 3 minutes
- Users > 125 < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
- Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds

Comment: Thanks! Might you know why this didn't kick in here for user:12874?

Comment: @anongoodnurse did you see my note I added about SX goes by UTC time?

Comment: I thought that they were all posted within one 24° period UTC. I'll double-check.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I linked a post answered by Jeff Atwood and summed it up in my post as well. Basically, the user would have to start a new account using a different IP to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.